# I have a variable probability stored a double value 0.00001,but when I get it from database ,it become "1.0E-5"

Tags: java, mysql

java entity:

```
@Table
public class Activity{
    @Column
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column        
    private Double probability;


    // Getter and Setter method omitted
}
```

mysql database table:

```
create table activity(
id bigint notnull primary key,
name varchar(60),
probability double
);
```

when I create a entity activity and insert it into database,show below:

```
+----+-------------------------+-------------+
| id | name                    | probability |
+----+-------------------------+-------------+
| 66 | test activity           |     0.00001 |
| 67 | test activity probility |       0.001 |
| 68 | test                    |     0.00001 |
+----+-------------------------+-------------+
```

when I get an activity entity,for example the id=68,its probability is 1.0E-5 ,why?

Comment: `0.00001` is the same as `1.0e-5` and is not represented exactly in IEEE754. http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 0):

> I have a variable probability stored a double value 0.00001,but when I get it from database ,it become “1.0E-5”

No. It went into scientific notation when you converted it to a String. The correct answer to that is DecimalFormat.

Comment: I have understood that, so I have change the variable type into BigDecimal,so this question is resolved,thanks your recommend!